# How to come back to initial screen after home button? Simulating a re-launch so to speak

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7

I am writing an app where upon launch, the user is presented with an alert popup asking for a password. If correct password is entered, then 2nd and 3rd screens can be displayed allowing the user to update certain values. They can then press home button. However, it is important for this app to remain active in the background and continue to monitor user activities.

In the meantime if the user decides to come back to my app by tapping/clicking app's icon, then the user is taken to the point where they left off. As if the app was never exited. And this is not what I want.

I would like to be able to go to the very first step again. As if, the app is re-launched while in fact it was alive and well, running in the background, so to speak. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change back to the original screen using the App Delegate's method

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}
```

which is meant to be used when the app is being reopened after being in the background. Add code in this method that makes it appear as though the app had just been opened and had not been in the background. Be aware that this method is also called if the phone was unlocked while your app was open.

Comment: If I disable state preservation, will it do the trick? i.e. go back to the launch screen? If so, how do I disable state preservation and do I include those statements in the applicationWillEnterForeground method or some other place? Thank you.

Comment: Is your app performing tasks in the background or can it be stopped when the app is closed by the user?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As for my app, it performs monitoring tasks in the background. It can also be closed by the user in which case there will be no background task.